# Alternative Interpretation of the Schwarzian Derivative

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras

The Schwarzian derivative of a holomorphic function $f$ of a complex variable $z$ is defined as $\{f, z\} = \frac{f^{\prime\prime\prime}(z)}{f^\prime(z)} - \frac{3}{2}{\Big(\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(z)}{f^\prime(z)}\Big)}^2$. It is invariant under all linear fractional transformations, that is, 
$\{g, z\}$ for  any linear fractional transformation $g(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$ equals zero.

The Schwarzian derivative has a nice geometric interpretation based on its definition as an operator that is invariant under linear fractional transformations. (Read Bill Thurston's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/38125/112368) to a question posted on MathOverflow long back for a geometric description.)

The way I understand it, when we're looking from a geometric point of view, a linear fractional transformation is defined as a homography on the complex projective line. However, a linear fractional transformation can also be defined as a homography over the projective line over a ring. (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography#Over_a_ring) for an explanation.)

> I'm interested in understanding if the definition of a linear
>   fractional transformation as a homography over the projective line
>   over a ring leads to (or can be used to obtain) an alternative
>   description of the Schwarzian derivative. (Say, a relatively more
>   algebraic description compared to the geometric one obtained from
>   the standard definition.)